# How to use aggregate as condition in WHERE clause?

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to achieve the average of employee salary at least $2,000

my query looks like below:

```
SELECT AVG(Salary) AS "salary"
FROM Wages
WHERE salary > 2000;
```

Unfortunately, the posgres return error message states that condition in WHERE clause can't incorporate AVG() function..

Any other alternative to solve this?

Comment: Your query works just fine and doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Do you want the average of salaries that greater than 2000 or return the average if that is greater than 2000?

Answer (score 0):

Your query is fine, but your alias `salary` is overriding the `salary` column such that when you refer to it in the `WHERE` clause Postgres thinks you mean the alias, rather than the column.  Just change the alias and it should work:

```sql
SELECT AVG(salary) AS avg_salary
FROM Wages
WHERE salary > 2000;
```

Comment: Nah, the test case looking for average salary, instead of counting the salary..'AND HAVING clause can only be paired with COUNT isn't it i.e. HAVING COUNT(attribute)>...?